# What's the length of the side of the square below?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: Two circles whose radii measure R are situated in such a way that the distance between their centers measures R. In the region common to both circles is inscribed a square , calculate the length of the side of the square.(Answer: $\frac{R}{2}(\sqrt7-1)$)
*Solution by geometry, not by analytics.

My progress:

[image]
$GF = l\\AI = JB = x\\
MF = \frac{DF}{2} \\
DF = l\sqrt2 \therefore MF = \frac{l\sqrt2}{2}\\
\triangle JFM: (R-x)^2+(\frac{l}{2})^2 = (\frac{l\sqrt2}{2})^2\implies\\
(\frac{R}{2}-x)^2 = \frac{l^2}{2}-\frac{l^2}{4} \implies (\frac{R}{2}-x)^2 = \frac{l^2}{4}$

needed to find the value of x

Comment: A related video: https://youtu.be/oS8yKLdvVYY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the triangle $AFJ$ where we know the length of $AF=R$. Using your notation, we can write $FJ=\frac{l}{2}$. Since $AB=R$ and $MJ=\frac{l}{2}$ we can find that $AJ=AM + MJ = \frac{R}{2} + \frac{l}{2}$. Now we can use the abc formula to solve for $l$.

Comment: I didn't understand.  $FJ =\frac{1}{2}$ ??? The $ACB$ video already shows the answer... Let $R = 1, FJ = x$ $ \triangle AFJ:1^2=  (0,5+x)^2+x^2\implies x=\frac{\sqrt7-1}{4} \therefore 2x=\frac{\sqrt7-1}{2}.R$

Comment: $FJ = \frac{l}{2}$ as $GF=l$. Hope this explains the confusion